# Running Ionic 3 app on iPhone throws error: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I am opening `.xcworkspace` of my Ionic 3 project and trying to run it on my device but I suddenly get the following error in Xcode:

```
Ld /Users/manuel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-awaxbzztsgokklgptpuoufwcwmkt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/MyApp normal arm64
    cd /Users/manuel/Documents/MyApp/dev/copernic4-ion2/galilei/platforms/ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk -L/Users/manuel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-awaxbzztsgokklgptpuoufwcwmkt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/manuel/Documents/MyApp/dev/copernic4-ion2/galilei/platforms/ios/MyApp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-google-analytics -F/Users/manuel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-awaxbzztsgokklgptpuoufwcwmkt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/manuel/Documents/MyApp/dev/copernic4-ion2/galilei/platforms/ios/Pods/OneSignal/iOS_SDK/OneSignalSDK/Framework -FMyApp/Plugins/com.googlemaps.ios -filelist /Users/manuel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-awaxbzztsgokklgptpuoufwcwmkt/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MyApp.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/manuel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-awaxbzztsgokklgptpuoufwcwmkt/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MyApp_lto.o -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -ObjC -framework OneSignal -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework UserNotifications /Users/manuel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-awaxbzztsgokklgptpuoufwcwmkt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a -framework Accelerate -framework CoreData -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreText -framework GLKit -framework ImageIO -lc++ -lz -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework GoogleMapsBase -framework GoogleMaps -framework GoogleMapsCore -framework EventKit -framework EventKitUI -framework AVFoundation -lGoogleAnalyticsServices -lAdIdAccess -framework AdSupport -lsqlite3 -weak_framework WebKit -lz -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/manuel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-awaxbzztsgokklgptpuoufwcwmkt/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MyApp_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/manuel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-awaxbzztsgokklgptpuoufwcwmkt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/MyApp

duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVLogger in:
    /Users/manuel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-awaxbzztsgokklgptpuoufwcwmkt/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVLogger.o
    /Users/manuel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-awaxbzztsgokklgptpuoufwcwmkt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a(CDVLogger.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVLogger in:
    /Users/manuel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-awaxbzztsgokklgptpuoufwcwmkt/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVLogger.o
    /Users/manuel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-awaxbzztsgokklgptpuoufwcwmkt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a(CDVLogger.o)
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't understand what is duplicated... any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate Symbols for Architecture arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303782/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-arm64)

Comment: Don't really know what to do with this...

Comment: @the4kman No it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

To solve the problem please have a look over this blog post from Cordova iOS 4.5.
http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/09/08/ios-release.html

You need to remove plugin "cordova-plugin-console" that is installed by default when generating a new Ionic project. Now this is in core part of cordova for iOS.

Comment: in case anyone's wondering how to remove plugin : cordova plugin remove FOLDER_PLUGIN_NAME

Answer (score 15):

Since duplicate symbols are there, just removed "-ObjC" from both Targets and Project:

Build Settings -> Linking -> Other linker flags.

also try to remove any unwanted  libraries from

Targets -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I tried everything so far! Nothing worked except for this. Thanks again

Comment: This answer is working if you are using old cordova versions.Many thanks

Comment: As an Obj-C developer your process was my gut-sense but since we are using ionic for this project it is logically correct process was to remove the duplicate via cordova.

Answer (score 10):

The problem here is cordova-ios@latest.

And we could fixed this issues with:

- Uninstall cordova-ios first, with `npm uninstall cordova-ios`
- Install cordova-ios with `npm install cordova-ios@4.4.0`
- After that we should add platform with `ionic cordova platform add ios@4.4.0`
- The last one, run `ionic cordova build ios`, that open with xcode and build with your settings.

Comment: This worked. I was at cordova-ios@4.5.4 to 4.4.0 and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

Since cordova IOS 4.5 they are including cordova-plugin-console, which results in the plugin being duplicated.
To fix just run:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-console
```

Comment: Yes, but this is just a simple response with the command to run to solve the problem.

Comment: this works for me, if your using latest ios cordova-plugin-console should be remove

Answer (score 0):

The solution **@arunraj414** worked for me, from xcode you can solve it this way:

[image]

Delete either one