# Resolve "Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error" with Ionic 3 and FCM

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic3

I build an Ionic 3 app and I try to use FCM to have push notifications.

I works in android. But when I try to deploy project on iOS I have this error : Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error.

I tried to remove and add iOS platform in my project but nothing better.

I open my project with .xcworkspace file, and I haven't Pod, I don't need it with Fcm. So this solution doesn't works for me ...
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1518

My Ionic Info :

```
cli packages: (/Users/ox/Documents/Mobile/ox/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.18.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.18.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.0
    Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.1

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
    ios-sim    : 5.0.13 
    Node       : v6.11.3
    npm        : 3.10.10 
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55
```

Any idea please ?

[image]

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46173762/running-ionic-3-app-on-iphone-throws-error-2-duplicate-symbols-for-architecture

Comment: @SurajRao I tried to remove cordova-plugin-console and build success on xcode. But app crash with this error on xcode : "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

Comment: @SurajRao I tried to rm and add platform again, but nothing better.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Ionic1, it was related to CocoaPods used by FCM, OneSignal and others.

On your platform/ios/:
 [image]

Try to start xcode from the .xcworkspace file. This should resolve the problem. At least resolved on other Ionic versions.

Comment: I already try to start xcode from this file. But I keep the error.. :/