# Duplicated Symbols

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine, game-development

Im making a game in Unity 2019, I export to iOS, then open with Xcode 11.6, made all the signing process, but when I want to build it I get:

> 81 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

and here is the full description:

https://justpaste.it/5uj8p

I tried:

- Removing the folder DerivedData
- Cleaning the solution Removed
- UnityAds from Unity (but still present on Xcode)
- Looking for "Other Linker Flags" and remove "-ObjC" as most answers said, but "Other Linker Flags" was empty.
- Locking GoogleAdsDependencies.xml as shown: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1355562/arm-64-function-not-4-byte-aligned-build-failed.html

Comment: Did you see this: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1355562/arm-64-function-not-4-byte-aligned-build-failed.html ?

Comment: tried that, didn't work.

Comment: As this looks like problems with UnityAds as most of the names in the logs suggests here is another post that might help you solve this: https://forum.unity.com/threads/ld-3-duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-arm64.860209/#post-5759587

Comment: And another thread with a different idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39512823/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-arm64-after-xcode-8-0-update
Hope any of this will help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the solution! It was the Google Unity Ads mediation plugin. So I removed the plugin and the issue is gone. How to get the plugin without the error? In the dependencies xml match the version of UnityAds that Unity is using. That's it.